# Converting date formats in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, format

I have a dataframe and the Date column has two different types of date formats going on.

`eg. 1983-11-10 00:00:00 and 10/11/1983`

I want them all to be the same type, how can I iterate through the Date column of my dataframe and convert the dates to one format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need parameter `dayfirst=True` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '1983-11-10 00:00:00', 1: '10/11/1983'}})
print (df)
                  Date
0  1983-11-10 00:00:00
1           10/11/1983


df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, dayfirst=True)
print (df)
        Date
0 1983-11-10
1 1983-11-10
```

because:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
print (df)
        Date
0 1983-11-10
1 1983-10-11
```

---

Or you can specify both formats and then use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
d1 = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce')

df['Date'] = d1.combine_first(d2)
print (df)
        Date
0 1983-11-10
1 1983-11-10
```

General solution for multiple formats:

```
from functools import reduce 

def convert_formats_to_datetimes(col, formats):
    out = [pd.to_datetime(col, format=x, errors='coerce') for x in formats]
    return reduce(lambda l,r: pd.Series.combine_first(l,r), out)

formats = ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%d/%m/%Y']
df['Date'] = df['Date'].pipe(convert_formats_to_datetimes, formats)
print (df)
        Date
0 1983-11-10
1 1983-11-10
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want them all to be the same type, how can I iterate through the
>   Date column of my dataframe and convert the dates to one format?

Your input data is ambiguous: is `10 / 11` 10th November or 11th October? You need to specify logic to determine which is appropriate. A function is useful if you with to try multiple date formats sequentially:

```
def date_apply_formats(s, form_lst):
    s = pd.to_datetime(s, format=form_lst[0], errors='coerce')
    for form in form_lst[1:]:
        s = s.fillna(pd.to_datetime(s, format=form, errors='coerce'))
    return s

df['Date'] = date_apply_formats(df['Date'], ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%d/%m/%Y'])
```

Priority is given to the first item in `form_lst`. The solution is extendible to an arbitrary number of provided formats.

Comment: @jezrael, Sure. Thankfully, SO lets you post answers that let you generalize OP's problems :).

Answer (score 0):

Input date is 
          NSECODE       Date       Close
1       NSE500  20000103   1291.5500
2       NSE500  20000104   1335.4500
3       NSE500  20000105   1303.8000

```
history_nseindex_df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(history_nseindex_df["Date"])
history_nseindex_df["Date"] = history_nseindex_df["Date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

ouput is now
       NSECode        Date       Close
1       NSE500  2000-01-03   1291.5500
2       NSE500  2000-01-04   1335.4500
3       NSE500  2000-01-05   1303.8000